# How just build docker image from Dockerfile with fabric8 docker-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, docker, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin

Here is a plugin defintion:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.26.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <registry>000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-aws-registy-0000000000000:latest</registry>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>my-image</name>
                        <build>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-aws-registy-0000000000000:latest</tag>
                            </tags>
                            <dockerFileDir>${project.build.directory}</dockerFileDir>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

After resource phase `Dockerfile` is copied to `target`. When I try to invoke `docker:build` goal I got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.25.2:build (default-cli)
on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal
io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.25.2:build failed: A tar file cannot include itself. -> [Help 1]
```

**What I want** - just simple execute `docker build -t .` command via maven *without* any plugin *packaging/building/assembly* goals (or subgoals).
Yesp this plugin have a lot of possibilities, but I need just docker build without any `tar` archiving and this have to be done from `target` folder.

How to do that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What docker does is to assemble all files that should be added to the image into a tar file and send this to the docker daemon for building the image.

The plugin creates this tar file in a sub-directory of the `target` folder (which is your `${project.build.directory}`). Taking the target folder as base for the docker plugin implicitly includes the tar file that is created, therefore the error that you get.

What I was doing in a project is to copy all the files that should be added to the image (`ADD`/`COPY`) and the `Dockerfile` to a `${project.build.directory}/dockerfile` directory and then create the image using `<dockerFileDir>${project.build.directory}/dockfile</dockerFileDir>`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use exec-maven-plugin to invoke docker itself?

I had the same issue like you and found out that if I place Dockerfile outside target folder, it works, e.g.

`<dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>`